# Lodash: Apply function to seed n times each time passing last calculation result

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Is there elegant lodash way to apply function to seed `n` times like

```
let start = 100, n = 3, multiplier = 1.2;

let predictions = _
  .range(1, 1 + n)
  .map(i => start * Math.pow(multiplier, i));

// => [120,144,172.8]
```

in more functional way like

```
let predictions = _
  .times(n)
  .something(curr => curr  * multiplier, /*seed*/ start);
```

Comment: That looks quite functional to me.

Comment: @AaditMShah sure, but sometimes I need something like half-map/half-reduce, so I'm just trying to find out is there someting similar in lodash.

Comment: Although I like the more general approach of the accepted answer better, it is possible to use map in this way it's ok to change the variable itself (or some intermediate variable), map could be used with `let predictions = _.times(n).map(s=>start = start * multiplier);` or wrapped in a function: `let predictions = (seed => _.times(n).map(s=>seed = seed * multiplier))(start);`

Comment: @Me.Name thanks, that is intresting option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sometimes I need something like half-map/half-reduce

What you're looking for is something like [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate). As far as I know, lodash doesn't have it. The next best thing is to define it yourself using [`_.mixin`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mixin) as follows:

```js
_.mixin({
    iterate: (n, f, x) =>
        _.reduce(_.times(n), arr => _.concat(arr, f(_.last(arr))), [x])
});
```

Now, you can use it as follows:

```js
let predictions = _
    .iterate(n, curr => curr * multiplier, start)
    .slice(1); // remove the start element
```

It's not the best solution. Using [`_.concat`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#concat) makes it really slow. You can optimize it if you'd like.